# wit.ai is not training new examples / training status stays "clean"

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, bots, training-data, wit.ai

yesterday I added a bunch of new training examples to my wit.ai-Project  but the training status got stuck somehow. The status always stays "clean" (green icon) when i add new examples – it seems, that the training process can't get triggered anymore. Thats pretty annoying, because none of the new examples work.

Can anybody help? Am I doing something wrong? (If someone at wit.ai reads this: Project name is ts_bot_dev_1).

Answer (score -1):

According to  [Wit.ai Hackers FB Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/withackers/210224716050450/) , there were some issues with training services in Wit the past couple days. It should be fixed by now.

Comment: This answer suggested a possible cause for your issue. Not sure why it is downvoted.